# How to check the inflation of a layout is complete

Tags: android, android-layout

In this code (in my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`):

```
mContext = getApplicationContext();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  Lat = 51.5074; Long = -0.1278;
    if (Lat == 0.0 && Long ==0.0) {
      mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
      getLastLocation();
      locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
          if (locationResult == null) {
            return;
          }
          for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            // Update UI with location data
            // ...
            Lat = location.getLatitude();
            Long = location.getLongitude();
          }
        }
      };
    } else{
      setupViewPager();
    }
  }
```

The setupViewPager starts with:

```
  private void setupViewPager() {
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this,
        getSupportFragmentManager(), Lat, Long);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userName = sharedPref.getString("signature", "");
    TextView uName =  findViewById(R.id.userName);
    if (!userName.equals("")) {
      uName.setText(userName);
    } else {
      uName.setText(R.string.app_name);
    }
```

and the error shows  `java.lang.NullPointerException` to the line:           `uName.setText(userName);`. To my understanding, this is because I am trying to `setText` too early, even before inflation of the layout is completed. The problematic `layout` is in `activity_main`.
For cases, where I don't set the Lat, Long before the if branch, it is working fine.

Is there any way that I wait and check for the inflation to be complete?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more code? As I understand you have a ViewPager with some UI (Views / Fragments)? Where do you call the first method with Lat Long? And whats the UI for it that you have a TextView inside? Do you use a activity to wrap this PagerAdapter?

If you use a fragment, you have "onViewCreated()", in activity probably in "onCreate()".

If you provide more code we can give you an more detailed and satisfying answer ;-)

Comment: I am sceptic about more code, because, the code is inflated in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`, and all the layouts are created before calling the `setupViewPager`. Though, I have added more code and text to be more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
TextView uName =  findViewById(R.id.userName);
```

Try instantiating it before the else statement?

At least all views should be instantiated first before anything to ensure you don't get a Null Pointer Reference.

Try putting it under

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Or create a view instantiating function/method and put it under that line.

Comment: Thats the first thing I have tried, without any success!! :(

Comment: Try Textview uName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName); otherwise, if it doesn't work, instantiate it on the class level like so: private TextView uName;